# Viewing a differential form on a manifold as a map $\mathfrak{X}(M) \times \cdots \mathfrak{X}(M) \rightarrow C^\infty(M)$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

I am used to viewing a differential form as a map $M \rightarrow \bigwedge^k(T_p^*M)$, where $\bigwedge^k(T_p^*M)$ is the set of all alternating multilinear maps on contangent space of $M$ at $p \in M$. In other words, we assign to each point in the manifold an alternating (covariant) tensor. This definition makes sense to me and is found in books such as Tu's *Introduction to Manifolds*.

I recently came across another definition in the book *Mathematical Gauge Theory* by Hamilton, where a differential form is defined as the map $\mathfrak{X}(M) \times \cdots \mathfrak{X}(M) \rightarrow C^\infty(M)$ that is $C^\infty(M)$-linear in each entry. $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ denotes the set of all vector fields on $M$. I do not fully understand this definition and have been having some trouble seeing how the two definitions are equivalent. Why is the range taken to be as general as $C^\infty(M)$?

Comment: The definition in the book from Hamilton probably also has the requirement that the multi linear map is alternating (or else this clearly does not define a differential form). This equivalence (Tensorfields = $C^\infty$ multi-linear maps) is called the tensor (-field) characterization lemma.

Comment: @jd27 Thank you, this lemma was exactly what I was looking for! And you are correct, Hamilton does require the map to be alternating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the case of vector fields (it is completely analogous for covector fields i.e. one-forms).

A smooth vector field $X$ on some smooth manifold $M$ is a smooth section of the tangent bundle $TM$, i.e. to every $p\in M$ we assign a vector $X_p\in T_pM$ varying smoothly with $p$. The vectors $X_p$ are operators on smooth functions on $M$. Given a smooth function $f\in C^\infty(M)$ we can apply the vector $X_p$ to $f$ to yield a real number $X_p(f)\in \mathbb R$.

In this way one can define the action of a vector field on a smooth function: $(X(f))_p:=X_p(f)$. So given a smooth vector field $X$ and a smooth function $f$, we get a new smooth function $X(f)\in C^\infty(M)$. In differential geometry it is now customary to identify the induced mapping
$$
C^\infty(M)\to C^\infty(M), \ f\mapsto X(f)
$$
with the vector field $X$ itself. Alternatively one has the induced mapping
$$
\Gamma(T^*M)\to C^\infty(M), \ \omega\mapsto X(\omega),
$$
where $X(\omega)$ is defined by $(X(\omega))(p):=\omega_p(X_p)$. The key fact about this mapping is (as noted in comments) that it is $C^\infty(M)$-linear.

For differential forms (and indeed general tensor fields) one can proceed in a very similar fashion. Let $\omega$ be a smooth $k$-form on $M$. Given smooth vector fields $X_1,\dots,X_k$ on $M$, we can define a smooth function
$$
\omega(X_1,\dots,X_k)\colon M\to \mathbb R, \ p\mapsto \omega_p(X_1(p),\dots,X_k(p)).
$$
Similarily to vector fields, this induces a mapping
$$
\Gamma(TM)\times \dots\times \Gamma(TM)\to C^\infty(M), \ (X_1,\dots,X_k)\mapsto \omega(X_1,\dots,X_k).
$$
It is again customary to identify the form $\omega$ with this mapping. This induced mapping will be $C^\infty(M)$-multilinear.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score -2):

This is based on my limited knowledge.
Let $\omega$ be a differential $k$-form.
$\omega_p(v_1,v_2,...,v_k)$ is a real number where $p \in M$, $v_i \in T_pM$ so this is a map from $M$ to $k$ - fold product of $T_pM^*$.

Now view this as $\omega_p(X_1(p),X_2(p),...,X_k(p))$ where $p \in M$ and $X_i$ is a vector field on $M$ and $X_i(p) \in T_pM$ and this quantity $\omega_p(X_1(p),X_2(p),...,X_k(p))$ is a smooth function on $M$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

This is similar to how tangent space has 2 equivalent definitions. One definition based on vector space and the other based on derivative of smooth functions w.r.t curves on $M$.

Both are consistent definitions but whether they are equivalent, needs to be verified.